# Open iOS app when a URL with a certain pattern is opened

Tags: ios, launch, url-scheme

I have successfully mapped my app to a custom URL Scheme, so when I type `myApp://path` my app opens. To do so I used `Info.plist`'s `CFBundleURLSchemes` and `CFBundleURLName`.

I wonder if I can map a URL *pattern* too, instead of the scheme, so when somebody types

http://mylegitdomain.info/blah

my app opens. This is possible in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way to do this - the `http:` and `https:` schemes automatically open Safari.

However, here's what you *could* do:

1. Register `mylegitdomain.info`
2. Run a server that simply redirects requests to `mylegitdomain.info` to `myApp://path`

This won't be *quite* as seamless to the user - the URL will open Safari and then redirect to your app - but it will work, and it might be worth it depending on your use case.

Comment: yeah I have legitdomain already running, I have to add code then so if the user is running IOS **and** the app is installed, it would perform a redirect instead of serving the page.

Comment: @rupps Yep, that sounds like a solution. Good luck!